# como realizar una matriz que muestre pares e impares y los multiplique por 2 y 3 respectivamente?

Tags: java, bluej

me encargaron realizar un programa para declarar y hacer 2 matrices, matriz1 y matriz2, y hacer un ciclo para leer enteros y guardalos en matriz1 lo cual creo que ya hice, despues hacer otro ciclo que analize los numeros de matriz1 y si es par, multiplicarlo por 2 y pasarlo a matriz2 y si es impar multiplicarlo por 3 y de nuevo pasarlo a matriz2 y luego mostrar las 2 matrices.

ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto es lo que llevo hasta el momento.

```
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(" numero de renglones " );
        int ren = Integer.parseInt(lector.nextLine());        
        System.out.print(" numero de columnas ");
        int col = Integer.parseInt(lector.nextLine());
        int [][] matrizent1 = new int[ren][col];
        int [][] matrizent2 = new int[col][ren];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrizent1.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < matrizent1[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" valor de la posicion " + i + ", " + j + ": ");
                matrizent1[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(lector.nextLine());
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < matrizent1.length; i++)
        {   
           for (int j = 0; j < matrizent1[i].length; j++)
           {
               matrizent2[j][i] = matrizent1[i][j];
           }
        }
        System.out.println(" matrizent1 ");
        for (int i = 0; i < matrizent1.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrizent1[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(matrizent1[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

se agradece mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Tu código como texto por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la siguiente modificación en tu segundo recorrido puede lograr tu objetivo.

```
for(int i = 0; i < matrizent1.length ; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < matrizent1[i].length ; j++){
        if(matrizent1[i][j] % 2 == 0){
           matrizent2[i][j] = matrizent1[i][j]*2;
        }else{
           matrizent2[i][j] = matrizent1[i][j]*3;
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que hace `matrizent[i][j]%2` es evaluar si el resto de dividir el número en la Zelda `matrizent[i][j]` es cero o no. Si es cero entonces significa que el número es par, caso contrario es impar. Espero te ayude :)

Comment: si había pensado en algo parecido pero no sabia si funcionaria, te agradezco mucho por tu ayuda rguzman :)